# Mount a samba share as regular user using cifs

Tags: ubuntu, samba, cifs

Server: Ubuntu SAMBA 3
Client: Ubuntu 12.04

I can access the shares using Nautilus but I can't mount the same share using shell.

I issue the following command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //auth.local/Aplicacao /home/josir/fontes -o rw,credentials=/home/josir/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,codepage=unicode,uid=1000,gid=1000
```

The share is mounted but I could not see any subdirectory. I tried to find out why issuing:

```
josir@MEDIA35:$ ls -ls | grep fontes
0 drw-rws--- 13 josir josir      0 Out  4  2011 fontes

josir@MEDIA35:$ ls -ls fontes
ls: impossível acessar fontes/Software: Permissão negada
ls: impossível acessar fontes/Doc: Permissão negada
ls: impossível acessar fontes/Scripts: Permissão negada
ls: impossível acessar fontes/HmlFontes: Permissão negada
```

**What am I missing ?**

What's the correct mount command to get access to this samba share?

Do I have to use the same uid/gid of the samba user ?

Comment: Have you checked the share permissions and the user permissions? My spanish is rusty, but it looks like it mounts ok, but that you then get access denied errors.

Comment: You almost get it - it's portuguese :)

Comment: When I issue the ls -ls is exactly to discover what permission I had on directory, that is. It's the correct permission but it's not the same gid/uid of samba server.

Comment: Is SELinux turned on and enforcing?

Comment: How do I know if SELinux is turned on?

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a directory for your mount

```
mkdir ~/share
```

2) Create a group with the same gid of your "Domain Users" group defined on your Samba Server:

```
sudo groupadd domain_users -g 1901
sudo addgroup josir domain_users
```

3) Mount using mount.cifs utility:

```
sudo mount.cifs //server/sharepoint ~/share -o user=josir dom=mediasys
```

Notes:

- To see if it works, you should logout and login (due to the addgroup command)
- To install mount.cifs: sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
- If you could not access the ~/share directory, pass (2) didn't work
  well...
- To know the gid Domain User, issue item (3) and then:

  ls -lsn | grep share